# An API or Library For Live Score Android Application

Tags: android

I want to write an application to update a live score like [livescore.com](http://www.livescore.com/)

Does it have any lib or api can give a live score?

Comment: Asking for off-site resources is considered off-topic for Stack Overflow nowadays (see item #5 on http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Agree with CommonsWare but to answer your question try this one out - http://xmlsoccer.com/